# I can't see the buttons because of the image sizes in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am trying to develop an application to display some food items in Django. Images overlay buttons when I try upload some of them. I tried solutions but couldn't fix the problem. I will be happy if you help me. Have a nice day.

```
{% extends 'foodApp/base.html' %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    </head>
<body>
 
    {% block body %}
 
    {% for item in item_list %}
        <div class="row m-5">
            <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-2">
                <img class="card" height="auto" src="{{ item.item_image }}"/>
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <a href="{% url 'foodApp:detail' item.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Details</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
 
    {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}    
 
    this is the old code
    
   
    <ul>
        <li>
           
            <a href=""> {{ item.id }} -- {{ item.item_name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
 
       
 
</body>
</html>
```

It is my index source code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baliY.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use  `<img class="card">`, you should use `<img class="card-img">`.

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends 'foodApp/base.html' %}

{% block head %}
<title>Food Items</title>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% for item in item_list %}
<div class="row m-5">
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-md-2">
        <img class="card-img" height="auto" src="{{ item.item_image }}"/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <a href="{% url 'foodApp:detail' item.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Details</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-8">
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```